# Array in autocomplete not showing anything

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, arrays

Here is my code for jQuery autocomplete:

PHP Code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users";
$users = db::getRecords($query);

$usernames = Array();
foreach ($users as $user) 
{
    $username[] = '"'.$user['username'].'"';
}
```

Array is associative.

JS:

```
$("#username").autocomplete({

    source: [<?php  echo join(',', $usernames); ?>],   
    select: function(event, ui) {

    }
});
```

This array `$user` is not getting converted into JavaScript array. Nothing happens when I type in my username input. How to define the source with PHP array?

Comment: what does `$users` contain? what does it look like? could you show the `print_r()/var_export()` of that variable?

Comment: @Ghost i have changed the code, please have a look

Comment: is this all in the same page?

Comment: did u check whether the query gives proper results?

Comment: yes ofc.... they are in same pge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you do it this way if you're in the same page.

In PHP:

```
$username = array();
$query = "SELECT * FROM users";
$users = db::getRecords($query);
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $username[] = array('id' => $user['id'], 'username' => $user['username'], 'label' => $user['username']);
}

$username = json_encode($username);
```

Then on JS:

```
$("#username").autocomplete({
    source: <?php echo $username; ?>,   
    select: function(event, ui) {
        alert(ui.item.id); // alets that user id
    }
});
```

But it strongly suggest separate the PHP, so that you'll only need to use `echo json_encode($data)` in that PHP.

Then use the php path to the `source: 'path/to/phpfile.php'`.

Comment: cool, that is working now. One more thing, in select: function(event, ui) can i find out what was the id

Comment: @MuhammadUmar i have a solution, it'l just take a sec, your array structure needs to be more than a simple flat array

Comment: hello @MuhammadUmar check my revision